# SQL - Select Query to get group by records whose sum(data) > 24

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select a UserID from the table whose sum of Data greater than 24.
I can able to select group and sum the records using

```
    SELECT SUM(DATA),UserID FROM TableName GROUP BY UserID
```

But how can I select only the records for which **SUM(DATA)>24**
I have tried

```
   SELECT SUM(DATA),UserID FROM #tempTimesheetValue where SUM(DATA)>24 GROUP BY UserID
```

But its not working.

Thanks in advance for suggestion..,

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`.

Comment: TRY `select UserID, SUM(DATA) FROM TABLE GROUP BY UserID HAVING SUM(DATA) > 24`

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by below query:

```
select UserID, DATA from (
 SELECT SUM(DATA) as DATA, UserID FROM #tempTimesheetValue GROUP BY UserID 
) A where DATA > 24
```

Answer (score 0):

The question might as well have the correct answer, which is;

```
SELECT SUM(DATA), UserID
FROM #tempTimesheetValue
GROUP BY UserID 
HAVING SUM(DATA) > 24;
```

A subquery could be used, but it is unnecessary complication.